# Laravel Paginator 'options' parameter

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, paginator

When creating a new instance of Laravel's Paginator, I know how to use all parameters of it's `__construct` method, except one. According to the [Paginator Laravel API page](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html), it should look like this:

```php
void __construct(mixed $items, int $perPage, int|null $currentPage = null, array $options = [])
```

I need help with the `options` parameter. The page says:

> ```
> Parameters
> ...   
> array    $options    (path, query, fragment, pageName)
> ```

What do all these options do and how do I use them? I couldn't find any proper documentation for this, and all information I have is a few examples of other fellow coders on SO using the `path` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely not needed anymore, but for future visits:

Nitpicking the docs to find each possible value the following was found:

Given the 4 possible values of the array (feel free to omit any one of the `'key' => value` pairs):

```php
['path' => '/categories/misc',    # Base Path for all generated links.

 'query' => ['sort' => 'age',     # Some additional variables on the links.
             'thing' => 5],

 'fragment' => 'SeaTurtles',      # Value that will appear after the '#' sign.

 'pageName' => 'myPageNumber']   /* The name of the variable used for
                                   pagination that will appear on the
                                   url/request. The default value is 'page'. */
```

Taking some "page number 3" as example case, these options would generate links in the form:

`http[s]://theSite.com/categories/misc?myPageNumber=3&sort=age&thing=5#SeaTurtles`

---

'path' -> [Documentation for Path Option](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#customizing-pagination-urls)

'query' -> [Documentation for Query Option](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values) (Note I could be mistaken on the syntax of this one.)

'fragment' -> [Documentation for Fragment Option](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#appending-hash-fragments)

'pageName' -> No Documentation. In AbstractPaginator Class it shows to be the default page number variable name that appears in the url after the '?'. It is shown in the ['path' Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#customizing-pagination-urls).

Comment: Thank you! Will make sure to remember this for future Laravel projects :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing specifically is using this `$options` parameter. When you pass this argument it sets `$options` on the class and it also iterates the `$options` array and sets the class variables with the names from the keys to the options. So you can use the "options" argument as a way to set some of the properties of the Paginator instance itself when you create one manually. You can also use it as extra data to pass with the Paginator as you have access to these options from `getOptions()`

Comment: What are these properties?

Comment: class member variables ... it literally does this `foreach ($options as $key => $value) { $this->{$key} = $value; }`

Comment: I understand how php arrays work, I'm asking what each specific option does (`path`, `query`, `fragment`, `pageName`). For example, I found out (after quite a bit of testing) that passing to the `$options` parameter this: `['path'=>url('myurl')]` sets the url of the paginator's links to `myurl`. I have no idea how to use the other three elements specified in the API page, and that's what I'd like to know.